# Python datetime function outputting duplicate entries for the month of 'May' for date formats in '%b %d, %Y' & '%B %d, %Y'

Tags: python, datetime

I am reading a text file with 5 columns. The 4th column contains date values in different date formats along with other data types.

Now, I am looking to output dates in the format '%b %d, %Y' and  '%B %d, %Y' to different text files.

Date format example:

%b %d, %Y -> Feb 17, 2009

%B %d, %Y -> February 17, 2009

The issue I am having is that, both the date formats will output the month of "May" twice because the 3 letter abbreviation for "May" is the same as the full month name.

Hence, to avoid the duplicates, I want to tell my program not to output any dates that have the month "May"  when the date format is "%b %d, %Y".

My code for the "%b %d, %Y" date format is provided at the bottom. I think I need to add an if statement to resolve this issue, but I am getting the following error message for my if statement. Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'row'

My Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

import csv

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as f_input, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f_output:

        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

        for row in csv_input:
            if datetime.date.row[3].strftime("%b") == 'May':
                pass
            else:
                for date_format in ['%b %d, %Y']:
                    try:
                        converted = datetime.strptime(row[3], date_format)
                        csv_output.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], converted.strftime(date_format), row[4]])
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution by adding the below if statement to my code.

```
    for date_format in ['%b %d, %Y']:
        try:
            converted = datetime.strptime(row[3], date_format)
            if datetime.date(converted).strftime("%b") == 'May':
                pass
            else:
                csv_output.writerow([row[0], row[1], row[2], converted.strftime(date_format), row[4]])
        except ValueError:
                pass
```